# How can you use a button and a text box to change a label?

Tags: c#, button, textbox, label

I'm just starting out and learning how to code in C Sharp. We have a class project where we need to make a program that is a guessing game of a random number between 1 and 100. I have that working (currently for testing I'm only doing 1-10), but I wanted to go a step past the basic code and add in a few touches of my own. I have four labels, two with words to describe what they are for, and two that I want the data in to change. Say you're guessing between 1 and 100, and you guess 25 and its to low and its the highest number you've guessed that is to low, I want that displayed, same if you guess a number like 70 and its to high I want that displayed in the label. It seems easy enough but I'm not having any luck with it. Being new to coding I'm going to post my whole code as I'm not sure where the error is. Please note since the code is not working, I only have it set up for the low number until I figure it out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        Double count = 0;
        int randomNumber;
        Random rand = new Random();





        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            randomNumber = rand.Next(10) + 1;
            lblLowShow.Text = "0";
            lblHighShow.Text = "100";
        }

        private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            int guessedNumber;
            guessedNumber = int.Parse(txtEnterGuess.Text);

            if (guessedNumber > randomNumber)
               {
                MessageBox.Show("To High! Please try again");
               }

            if (guessedNumber < randomNumber)
               {
                    int lowguess;
                    MessageBox.Show("To Low! Please try again");
                    lowguess = Convert.ToInt32(lblLowShow);

                    if (guessedNumber < lowguess) // Changes the number of the highest, low guess that is displayed.
                        {
                            string LowShow;
                            LowShow = lowguess.ToString();
                            lblLowShow.Text = LowShow;
                        }
                }

            else
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You won in " + count + " tries!");
                  count = 0;
                  randomNumber = rand.Next(10) + 1;
              }


        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnNewGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Visual studio isn't doing any of the red dots to show an error in the code, so that's not helping me track down the mistake(s).

Comment: what's the exact problem here? can you explain it?

Comment: When I put in a number and run the code, say I put in the number 2, and hit guess, I get this error message.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: you need to track the LAST guess in a separate variable and compare that, rather than comparing values entered into labels etc. thus, simply add a new variable called lastGuess and set it as the LAST action in the `btnGuess_Click` event, then compare on re-entry -same with the lastRandomNumber (these would be module level vars)

Comment: thus, you'd have a final two lines that read: `lastrandomNumber = randomNumber;` and `lastGuessedNumber = guessedNumber;`

Comment: Thank you Jim Tollan.

I took Jim's advice and tweated the code I'm using a little to:

                    if (guessedNumber < LastNumber) // Changes the number of the highest, low guess that is displayed.
                        {
                            LastNumber = guessedNumber;
                            lblLowShow.Text = LastNumber.ToString();
                        }

I set LastNumber as an int at the top of the code. I can run the code and no longer get an error message, but lblLowShow, doesn't change.

Comment: Alright so the code is no longer throwing errors, but I can't get the text in the labels to change. If I just do `lblLowShow.Text = Convert.ToString(guessedNumber)` Then is changes but say the number is 50, you guessed 25 once, then you pick 15, which is lower than 25, I want it to keep 25 as the highest, to low guess. Doing it the way above changes the number even if its lower than a different guess. @Slashy fixed the win error, now I think this label thing is the last problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a simple `else` statment before the  condition of if the guessed number is lower then the desired number. That's why the computer goes directly to the next `if` statment and prints a message that the user won the game.

just this:

```
         else//
        if (guessedNumber < randomNumber)
           {
                int lowguess;
                MessageBox.Show("To Low! Please try again");
                lowguess = Convert.ToInt32(lblLowShow);

                if (guessedNumber < lowguess) // Changes the number of the highest, low guess that is displayed.
                    {
                        string LowShow;
                        LowShow = lowguess.ToString();
                        lblLowShow.Text = LowShow;
                    }
            }
```

Comment: @Lyght if i helped you i would very appreciate if you could mark my answer :) thanks.